# The error is existed when setup the workflow in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

When I configure the workflow. I have got an error message like that.

[image]

> System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: The user name
>   'user@domain' is invalid. ---> System.ArgumentException: The
>   user name 'user@domain' is invalid.    at
>   System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord
>   errorRecord)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()    at
>   System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.CommandletHelper.InvokePowershell(Command
>   command, Action`3 updateProgress)    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.CommandletHelper.CreateDefaultNamespace(String
>   sbnamespace, String[] managedUsers, Action`3 updateProgress)    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.ProgressPageViewModel.NewSBNamespace(FarmCreationModel
>   model, Boolean errorOnFailure, Boolean isFirstCommand)

I've tried to research but don't get anything. Please help!

Comment: Check the event viewer -> Application for a better explanation of the error. If error is related to SQL add the user has sysadmin (yes I know is not good..) and retry

Comment: @Max It's exactly the error from SQL. But I don't know to add the user to what database.

Comment: Open SQL Server Managerment studio, expand the Security node, find the user, right click, roles select the sysadmin role, close and try